# How to get the value of from a list in a component in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs, reactjs-flux

This is a React component I have created:

```
<li>
    <a href="#">{this.props.header}</a>
    <ul className="submenu">
        <span>
            <li>
                <a href="#" ref="filterValue" onClick={this.onClick}>{skillsList}</a>
            </li>
        </span>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Here is the `onClick` function I have defined:

```
onClick: function() {
    FilterClickAction.print(this.refs.filterValue.getDOMNode().textContent);
}
```

Here is the `FilterClickAction` action:

```
module.exports = {
    print: function (filterValue) {
       console.log('filter value is', filterValue);
    }
};
```

But this action is returning all the values that are coming to the link and not just the value of the link that was clicked. How can I get only the value associated with the link that was clicked?

Comment: You need to grab the value from the event and not the refs, using `event.target` and then whatever you want to fetch.

Answer (score 1):

Have your event handler take the value as its first argument...

```
onClick: function(skillsList, event) {
  event.preventDefault()
  // ...
}
```

...and [use `Function.prototype.bind()` to partially apply the value to be passed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind#Partial_Functions) when the event handler is called:

```
<a onClick={this.onClick.bind(this, skillsList)>{skillsList}</a>
```